# How to set a value from body request to existing object with typescript? ts(2322)

Tags: typescript, express, iteration, put, for-in-loop

Sending put http call with express js. While using typescript and trying to iterate through the object,
I'm getting an error "Type 'any' is not assignable to type 'never'"

```
    let i: keyof typeof foundArticle;

    for (i in foundArticle) {
        if (req.body[i]) {

        //console.log(foundArticle[i]) // works ok

        foundArticle[i] = req.body[i]; // this line throws an error in ts, still executes
      
        }
    }
```

It's working just fine with javascript,
is there a way to set/overwrite a value from body request to existing object with typescript?

Comment: Your problem is somewhere else. Check where `foundArticle` is defined.

Comment: let foundArticle = articles.find(
        (article) => article.id === +req.params.id
    ); 
       //   foundArticle.title = req.body.title; // this also work without warning. 
       //   foundArticle['title'] = req.body['title']; //works same without warning. 
     
      it looks like foundArticle can be edited
      just don't get why cannot do this with variable

Comment: I think I noticed the problem. You defined `let i: keyof typeof foundArticle` and used it in the for loop. If you defined `let i: string` you wont have the error message. Also normally you can just define `i` inside of the for loop `for (const i in foundArticle)`

Comment: if you define `i` as string you would get the `cannot use string as index of ....` error, no the error you're getting is because you use `articles.find()` which returns `<T> | undefined`. `undefined[i]` is of type never so before you enter the `for ... in` loop you should check if `foundArticle` is actually there